# jquery scroll load more don't working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm try to load more data on scroll touch bottom, but dont' working in any page...

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(document).height() <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
        alert("End Of The Page");
    }
 });
```

I don't know why, because if I put only for test:

```
 alert("End Of The Page");
 $("#test").html('test');
```

The jquery and javascript is working/loaded...

Comment: have you tried logging the values to see if your `if` is correct - it looks wrong to me

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me. May be you have messed up while replacing the alert.
Hit F12 and see the error listed in console if the code still doesn't work.

Here's the exact code you provided

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).height() <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
        $("#test").html('test');
    }
});
```

Fiddle:
`https://jsfiddle.net/3dvro7wy/1/`